# bind one of 2 screens to one virtual desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, mate, multiple-desktops

i will do a workshop. i'd like the audience see all the time only one desktop. there will be one application visible

i, on my laptop, want to be able to switch between what audience see and what they don't see. without changing what audience see in the meantime.

so my first idea is to bind audience view to one virtual desktop. is it possible? or maybe there are other ways of doing this?

i'm on ubuntu 14.04, mate 1.8.2, nvidia, dell precision

Comment: With extended desktop can't it work so your laptop screen shows one thing and the audience via HDMI or projector sees something else and you can just look at the audience's screen to see what they see? Maybe use a lazer pointer or something in your hand when you look at their screen?

Comment: nope, i'll have the audience screen behind my back so i can't code this way

Comment: What about a second screen on your desk that shows you what the audience sees?

Comment: good idea but i can't be sure i will have additional screen

Comment: If you can read backwards you could use a big mirror :p